# How to get the current language?

Tags: locale

With a text file, is there a way to access to the current language, for example `en_US` or `en_US.UTF-8`?

Does Emacs provide a function to get the current locale/language?

---

Some context, I'm making a package that provides presets dealing with common words for different languages (mostly programming languages).

While not the primary purpose of the package I have added an English language preset that includes days-of-week, months-of-the-year ... etc. It would be good if I could select a preset based on the users language in a way that works on all major platforms (Unix/macOS/Windows).

So I want to be able to load `my-preset-en.el` or `my-preset-hr.el` based on the users local - in a portable way.

Comment: Take a look at the function `describe-language-environment`.

Comment: But note that Emacs as a whole has a single language environment; you cannot choose different language environments in different buffers.

Comment: You can always run a shell command: `M-! locale` or `(shell-command "locale" some-buffer)`.

Comment: What aspect of the language environment are you interested in? If it's how Emacs encode the file on writing, you can look at `buffer-file-coding-system`.

Comment: @db48x if this is not per-buffer, then the buffer part of the question wasn't important.

Comment: @Lindydancer checked, this only shows `utf-8` here (nothing related to English)

Comment: @aadcg are you suggesting to use this function in place or copy-paste code from it?

Comment: @ideasman42, we have no idea what you are really trying to do. The real answer to the question will depend on your real goal. However, `describe-language-environment` is not really intended for use inside of other functions, because it doesn’t return anything. Instead it opens up a buffer for the user to read from. If you want some code to know what language environment the user has chosen, just look at the `current-language-environment` variable.

Comment: @ideasman42 I'm just trying to point out you to the right direction, as it's not clear what your goals are.

Comment: @db48x & @aadcg - added some context to the question, although I'm not sure it changes much it's possible there is something specific in my use case which could impact the answer. I think it boils down to: `a portable way to access the current LOCALE` although if there was some other setting that stored the language, it would likely be just as useful.

Comment: `(getenv "LANG")`?

Comment: @NickD the issue with this is it may return "C", it also misses `win32` `w32-get-locale-info` and `w32-get-valid-locale-ids` which `get-locale-names` in `mule-cmds.el` is using, so it seems a portable version of this ends up having to be more involved (hence my question).

Comment: Well, if the locale is `C`, how is Emacs supposed to know what the language is? The user has to specify *something* somehow in order for the language to be known. Although I believe that the `C` locale uses `English` as the language (for messages and such) so you can add an exceptional case.

Comment: @NickD the environment has arbitrary values yet I still want to do something sensible from the user perspective. Yes, C is probably `en` or `en_US` or similar. I'm just pointing out this isn't as simple as calling `(getenv "LANG")` if I'm to redistribute code that works on other peoples systems.